# Django: Converting an entire set of a Model's objects into a single dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-models, dictionary

*If you came here from Google looking for model to dict, skip my question, and just jump down to the first answer. My question will only confuse you.*

Is there a good way in Django to  entire set of a Model's objects into a single dictionary? I mean, like this:

```
class DictModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(20)
    value = models.CharField(200)


DictModel.objects.all().to_dict()
```

... with the result being a dictionary with the key/value pairs made up of records in the Model? Has anyone else seen this as being useful for them?

Thanks.

**Update**
I just wanted to add is that my ultimate goal is to be able to do a simple variable lookup inside a Template. Something like:

```
{{ DictModel.exampleKey }}
```

With a result of DictModel.objects.get(key__exact=exampleKey).value

Overall, though, you guys have really surprised me with how helpful allof your responses are, and how different the ways to approach it can be. Thanks a lot.


**Update October 2011:**
This question is the top result if you Google "django model_to_dict", which is actually pretty awful given that it solves a different problem than what I was asking.

What I wanted was to be able to map all of the instances in a queryset into a single dictionary with a specified model field as the key.
model_to_dict, on the other hand converts a single model instance into a dictionary.

Now, my needs at the time were pretty darn specific, and probably extremely rare (I can't even remember the project I needed it for, or why). So I would be pretty surprised that anyone looking for information about model_to_dict is going to find my question actually useful. Sorry.

model_to_dict seems to be a much more common usage case than I had.


**Update Dec 2011:**
I changed the title to hopefully better reflect my original intent.

Comment: If you are looking for how to convert a single django model to a dictionary, please go here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21925671/2800876

Comment: `list_of_json = [model_to_dict(model) for model in list_of_models]`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1123354/11875147) is the only answer which **fully answers the OP's exact question**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does this need to create an actual dict? could you get by with only something that looked like a dict?

```
class DictModelAdaptor():
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.model.objects.get(key=key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        pair = self.model()
        pair.key = key
        pair.value = item
        pair.save()

    def __contains__(self, key):
        ...
```

You could then wrap a model in this way:

```
modelDict = DictModelAdaptor(DictModel)
modelDict["name"] = "Bob Jones"
```

etc...

Comment: If this works in Template variable lookups, this may actually be what I want. Have you tried this? It'll be a few hours before I can.

Comment: Yes, I have used container adapters in many situations, although I have certainly not wanted to use a whole model in this way.  Also please note that this example is somewhat abbreviated.  You will want to add some additional handlers and proper error handling.

Comment: I picked this answer because it fits my specific situation the best (which is slightly more complicated a situation than I described). The other responses were great, and worked fine as well.

My favorite part was that lookups are done one at a time, instead of loading the whole table at once. I didn't even realize I wanted that until I saw it.

Answer (score 216):

You can also rely on django code already written ;).

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(instance, fields=[], exclude=[])
```

Comment: It is very nice solution but I've noticed that there is a catch. Since this method was written for usage in forms it doesn't dump fields that have editable=False flag.

Comment: It might be added that this doesn't seem to get the fields of a parent model.

Comment: `model_to_dict(instance, fields=[field.name for field in instance._meta.fields])`

Comment: Given how highly rated this answer is, I feel the need to point out that model_to_dict offers something fundamentally different than what I was originally asking for.

model_to_dict turns a single model instance into a dictionary, which is great.

What I wanted was to be able to map all of the instances in a queryset into a single dictionary with a specified model field as the key.

Comment: @LarrikJ From your question, I can't deduce that that is what you wanted at all. Moreover, using `model_to_dict` allows you to achieve exactly what you said your end goal was. And let's not forget, the title of your question is "Converting an entire Model into a single dictionary"

Comment: `model_to_dict(instance, fields=[field.name for field in instance._meta.fields])` will NOT dump fields that have `editable=False` flag. Use this instead: `{field.name: field.value_from_object(instance) for field in instance._meta.fields}`

Answer (score 26):

You are looking for the [Values member of QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields) which allows you to get a list of dictionaries from your query

> Returns a ValuesQuerySet -- a QuerySet
>   that evaluates to a list of
>   dictionaries instead of model-instance
>   objects. Each of those dictionaries represents
>   an object, with the keys corresponding
>   to the attribute names of model
>   objects.

```
>>> Blog.objects.values()
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog', 'tagline': 'All the latest Beatles news.'}],
>>> Blog.objects.values('id', 'name')
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog'}]
```

Comment: I don't think he wants a list of dict, he wants a single dict where key is model key

Comment: `.values()` not returns values from fields such as `ImageField()` etc.

Answer (score 17):

You want the [`in_bulk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) queryset method which, according to the docs:

> Takes a list of field values (`id_list`) and the `field_name` for those values, and returns a dictionary mapping each value to an instance of the object with the given field value. If `id_list` isn’t provided, all objects in the queryset are returned. `field_name` must be a unique field, and it defaults to the primary key.

It takes a list of IDs, so you'll need to get that first via the `values_list` method:

```
ids = MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
ids_to_model_instances = MyModel.objects.in_bulk(ids)
# {1: <MyModel: 1>, 2: <MyModel: 2>, 3: <MyModel: 3>}
```

Comment: While this doesn't help me in this instance, that's pretty neat and I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: Django allows you to have primary keys that are not integers.  If your model is set up properly in this way, this might still be a good solution.

Comment: i am doing exactly the same thing. i got ids but i want the data across these ids in an array. kindly help me

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `python` [serializer](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization):

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('python', DictModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: I haven't tried Django's serializers yet, so I'm having trouble figuring out how this would work. I think I'll need to try this idea in an interactive session. It seems like it could be a solution, though. Thanks.

Comment: django `serializers` can do serializations to `queryset`, while `model_to_dict` can only serialize to model instance.

Answer (score 8):

use

```
dict(((m.key, m.value) for m in DictModel.objects.all())
```

As suggested by Tom Leys, we do not need to get whole object, we can get only those values we need e.g.

```
dict(((m['key'], m['value']) for m in DictModel.objects.values('key', 'value')))
```

and if you need all values, it is better to keep whole object in dict e.g.

```
dict(((m.key, m) for m in DictModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: We should combine solutions - dict(((m['key'], m['value']) for m in DictModel.objects.all().values()) - this way the hidden id field isn't returned from the DB.

Comment: ILY, your answer is the **only answer which answers the OP's exact question** (and also my question).

Answer (score 6):

`dict((x.name, getattr(o, x.name)) for x in o._meta.fields)`

Comment: One of differences between this and Luper's solution with serialize('python', ...) is that here foreign key fields will be represented as actual related objects. Using serialize you will get only id value of related object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but Django objects have a `__dict__` attribute which seems be what you want.

Comment: Can't seem to find it here. It says [My Model Object] has no attribute 'dict'

Comment: I think @ben meant `__dict__`.

Answer (score 2):

To get values of a models into dictionary, add below code at the place where u need that dictionary

```
from models import DictModel

activity_map = dict(Plan.objects.values_list('key', 'value'))
```

activity_map is a dictionary which contains required information .

Answer (score 2):

```
user = mymodel.objects.all()
user.values()
```

You  can also try

```
user.values_list() # getting as list
```

Answer (score 1):

Or were you trying to do something like:

```
def someview(req):
    models = MyModel.objects.all()
    toTuple = lambda field: (getattr(field, 'someatt'), getattr(field, 'someotheratt'))  
    data = dict(map(toTuple,models))
    return render_to_response(template, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a map of all of the instances in a queryset into a single dictionary with a specified model field as the key, try doing this

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from myApp.models import myModel

allObjs = myModel.objects.all()
f = {}         # initialise the output
key = 'key'    # one of the fields from myModel

[f.update({x[key]: x}) for x in [model_to_dict(y) for y in allObjs]]
return f
```