# Django initiate form fields with model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I thought it looks trivial, and was surprised.

### What I have

I have a Django model + form (ModelForm).

My user fills in the form, and on my view I have the usual:

```
    if request.POST:
        form = myForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        result = form.save(commit=False)
```

Now I need to *heavily* manipulate some fields of the form (in the "result" object) and I want to check the forms `is_valid()` again before saving.

### The Problem

I tried to create a new form using the "result" object (that is a ModelForm object) using a dictionary (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123337/django-converting-an-entire-model-into-a-single-dictionary))

```
result_dictionary = dict((x.name, getattr(result, x.name)) for x in result._meta.fields)
```

or

```
result_dictionary = model_to_dict(result, fields=[field.name for field in result._meta.fields])
```

plus

```
testForm = myForm(initial=result_dictionary)
```

but it doesn't pass is_valid() **and does'nt give any errors!**
The fields are passed OK to the new form...

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any reason you are not using the "instance" parameter to create the form from the "result" object? - e.g. testForm = myForm(instance=result)

Comment: Happy too early.. This doesn't work right. `testForm.is_bound => False` and also `testForm.is_valid() => False`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, looking in the Django source can be really helpful, here's `BaseForm.is_valid()`:

```
def is_valid(self):
    """
    Returns True if the form has no errors. Otherwise, False. If errors are
    being ignored, returns False.
    """
    return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
```

So if there are no errors, `is_valid()` returns false because you haven't bound the form, you haven't given the form anywhere to look for data. Try using the `form.data` dictionary instead, something like this:

```
if request.POST:
    form = myModel(request.POST)
if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
    form.data['field1'] = 'Changing this'
    form.data['field2'] = 34

    testform = myModel(data=form.data)
```

Comment: Without changing the rest I tested `if testForm.is_bound:...` and it returns True. Or is this test wrong?   (p.s. I had a typo and corrected my question myModel-->myForm. Doesn't change anything - just to be less confusing)

Comment: If `testForm.is_bound` is True, and `testForm.errors` is empty as well, then `testForm.is_valid()` should really, really return True, by all logical senses I have ;) Have you tried looking at `testForm.errors`?