# Django: custom object json serialization

Tags: python, json, django

I want to serialize a custom object in json format, where entryData is a list of my domain object. Something like this:

```
{
    "total":2,
    "current":1,
    "entryData":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "version":0,
            "name":"Default Station"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "version":3,
            "name":"Default Station 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here what I have done to get json output in one of my attempt:

```
def ground_station_listgrid(request):
    entryData = serializers.serialize("json", GroundStation.objects.all())
    response_data = {}
    response_data['totalPages'] = 2
    response_data['currentPage'] = 1
    response_data['entryData'] = entryData

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),mimetype='application/json')
```

but the result is entryData evaluated as a string, with quotes escaped:

```
{
"totalPages": 1, 
"currentPage": 1, 
"entryData": "[{\"pk\": 1, \"model\": \"satview.groundstation\", ....
```

I have also tryed to do something like this:

```
def ground_station_listgrid(request):

    response_data = {}
    response_data['totalPages'] = 1
    response_data['currentPage'] = 1
    response_data['entryData'] = GroundStation.objects.all()

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),mimetype='application/json')
```

But I get this exception: `[<GroundStation: nome>, <GroundStation: nome>, <GroundStation: nome>] is not JSON serializable`

Can someone please poin  me in right direction?

Thanks in advance
Marco

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [model_to_dict()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L112):

```
def ground_station_listgrid(request):
    data = [model_to_dict(instance) for instance in GroundStation.objects.all()]
    response_data = {}
    response_data['totalPages'] = 1
    response_data['currentPage'] = 1
    response_data['entryData'] = data

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),mimetype='application/json')
```

Though I prefer to use included in django batteries: [django.core.serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/), but, since you have a custom json response, `model_to_dict()` appears to be the way to go.

There are other options here (like use of `values_list()`):

- [<Django object > is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable)
- [Django: Converting an entire set of a Model's objects into a single dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123337/django-converting-an-entire-set-of-a-models-objects-into-a-single-dictionary)