# How to create an object using another model with same attributes in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

is it possible to create an object using another object which model has the same attributes?

In my case, I have two models - `TemporaryJob` and `Job`. The `TemporaryJob` is created when user fills the form. Next thing is to confirm. If he confirms `TemporaryJob`, the object should be converted to regular `Job` object.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    attributes
    methods

class TemporaryJob(Job):
    pass
```

I've tried `Job.objects.create(temporary_job_instance)` but it does not work.

Comment: Why not just using a `confirmed` attribute?

Comment: Because there is a signal that Job has been created which sends email to admin. So in this case admin would gets email after creation non-confirmed job.

Comment: Well, that is a matter of signal handling.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this using signals or whatever?

Comment: @GaneshJadhav I don't remember but I think @ Serafeims answer is worth to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Klaus D. comment is correct: I also don't think that your design is correct. Instead of having `Job` and `TemporaryJob` models with similar fields you should only have a `Job` model that has a boolean `is_temporary` field that would be `True` of this is a temporary job or `False` if not. If you go this way then you wouldn't need to copy the values between tables. All other problems you'll experience will be resolved *more* easily if you have normalized data.

In any case, to actually answer your question, notice that `objects.create()` is using kwargs (i.e it should be called like `Job.objects.create(attr1=val1, att2=val2)` etc. The best way to output these kwargs is to create a dictionary with the values of the object you want to pass (the values of `temporary_job_instance`) and pass it to `create` using the unpacking syntax (`**`). So, if `values` is a dictionary with the values of `temporary_job_instance`, you could just call `Job.objects.create(**values)`.

Now you just need to create the `values` dict from your `temporary_job_instance`. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do that in django :( It can be done though -- you can take a look at theses questions for some insight and a lot of methods of doing it: [Convert Django Model object to dict with all of the fields intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact) or this [Django: Converting an entire set of a Model's objects into a single dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123337/django-converting-an-entire-set-of-a-models-objects-into-a-single-dictionary)

Answer (score 8):

This is what I do. Could be bad if you save your temporary_job_instance, so just don't.

```
a_dict = temporary_job_instance.__dict__
del a_dict['_state']
del a_dict['id']
Job.objects.create(**a_dict)
```